# Bootstrap-select dropdown not clickable

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using Bootstrap-select && pixit admin panel from themeforset 
the dropdown is behaving so weird sometimes it's clickable and sometimes it's not.
The page link : [The error link](http://ads.admentions.com/apply)

```
<select name="website_lang" class="form-control required" data-live-search="true">
    <?php foreach ($this->Tools_model->languages() as $key => $value) : 
       echo "<option value='{$key}'>{$value}</option>";
     endforeach;  ?>
</select>
```

The Panel I am using [PIXIT](http://themeforest.net/item/pixit-admin-frontend-template/7528815)

I am fetching countries using php inside of the list but i don't think that this is the problem.
any ideas ?

Comment: *"any ideas ?"* - Any code? Edit: You're welcome, glad it worked out.

Comment: I found out that i forgot to add </select> after fetching the options , i am going to remove the question. Thanks.

Comment: i discovered that's the problem still exists i will provide the codes in my question will edit it.

Comment: Sorry Mostafa, I don't.